# How to view first 100 lines of .csv file in an S3 bucket using 'cat' command in aws cli?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've tried

```
aws s3 cat s3://<BUCKET_NAME>/<SUB-FOLDER>/<FILE_NAME> | -10
```

This returned an error: `command not found`

```
aws s3 cat s3://<BUCKET_NAME>/<SUB-FOLDER>/<FILE_NAME> -cat
```

This returned an error: `An error occurred (InvalidObjectState) when calling the GetObject operation: The operation is not valid for the object's storage class`

Is there a simple way to view the first 10, 100, or n lines of a given file stored in an s3 bucket?

Comment: Did you mean to have something like `head -n 10` (or just `head` as the default is 10 lines) for the first command?  What is the command `-10` that you're piping to?

Comment: I meant to output the 10 line after the header line in the file.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such `s3` command as "cat" (see the available commands [here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/index.html#available-commands)).  To do what you want you'll do something like:

```
aws s3 cp s3://<BUCKET_NAME>/<SUB-FOLDER>/<FILE_NAME> - | head -10
```

which would get the first 10 lines.  Note that this will copy the entire file to your machine before it pipes it to the `head` command.  This is fine for 100 line files.  But giant files will take time and bandwidth.